# Android Azure SDK - NullPointerException when I try to load something from blob storage

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I've created a container on Azure called 'assetcontainer'.

I've followed the sample to create the following code:

```
 CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(BuildConfig.AzureConnectionString);
        mClient = account.createCloudBlobClient();
        mAssetContainer = mClient.getContainerReference("assetcontainer");


        // Download the blob
        // For each item in the container
        for (ListBlobItem blobItem : mAssetContainer.listBlobs()) {
            // If the item is a blob, not a virtual directory
            if (blobItem instanceof CloudBlockBlob) {
                // Download the text
                CloudBlockBlob retrievedBlob = (CloudBlockBlob) blobItem;

                try {
                    retrievedBlob.download(new FileOutputStream(mContext.getFilesDir() + "\\assets\\" + ((CloudBlockBlob) blobItem).getName()));
                }
                catch(Exception ex){}
            }
        }
```

And I am receiving the following exception when I try to iterate the listBlobs():

```
Process: com.training.app.debug, PID: 3284
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.training.app.debug/com.training.app.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:783)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
            at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:145)
            at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:252)
            at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:109)
            at com.training.azure.AzureStorage.syncAssets(AzureStorage.java:57)
            at com.training.app.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm not sure what could be wrong here... Is this a bug with the azure sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution from [this page](http://android-er.blogspot.fi/2012/04/androidosnetworkonmainthreadexception.html), and it worked for me.

Android doesn't allow performing network operations in the main thread, so you need to execute the code in an asynchronous task, like this:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
 @Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(BuildConfig.AzureConnectionString);
    mClient = account.createCloudBlobClient();
    mAssetContainer = mClient.getContainerReference("assetcontainer");


    // Download the blob
    // For each item in the container
    for (ListBlobItem blobItem : mAssetContainer.listBlobs()) {
        // If the item is a blob, not a virtual directory
        if (blobItem instanceof CloudBlockBlob) {
            // Download the text
            CloudBlockBlob retrievedBlob = (CloudBlockBlob) blobItem;

            try {
                retrievedBlob.download(new FileOutputStream(mContext.getFilesDir() + "\\assets\\" + ((CloudBlockBlob) blobItem).getName()));
            }
            catch(Exception ex){}
        }
    }
}
}
```

Then you call `new MyTask().execute()` in the main thread.

Comment: I ended up finding this too! It is odd that the documentation doesn't mention this anywhere and the actual error is a bit difficult to find!

Comment: @Mr_E We've released a new version of the library (0.3.1) to address this issue. You can grab the code [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android). You should now receive the correct error message.

Comment: I'm running in a task (in doInBackground()) and am still getting this error. Bummer for me.